# How to limit what fields are returned through the WP API Backbone JS client

Tags: rest-api, backbone

If I fetch data from the WP JSON API via a URL, I can specify in the URL what fields should be returned. How can I do this when using Backbone JS?

I would expect it to be something like this:

```
postsCollection.fetch( { data: { per_page: 12 }, _fields: ["id"] } )
```

But the above does nothing for _fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  **_fields** option needs to be ***within*** the **data** parameter object, so your syntax should be:

```
postsCollection.fetch( { data: { per_page: 12, _fields: ["id"] }} )
```

Of course, you need to wait for the fetch and then process the resulting posts. For example:

```
 var postsCollection = new wp.api.collections.Posts();

  postsCollection
    .fetch({ data: { id: 1234, _fields: "title, status" } })
    .then((posts) => {

      console.log(posts);  // for example
        
    });
```

In this example, only the fields for **title** and **status** will be fetched.